# Push notifications on content change

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

Let's say I have an Android application that simply builds a ListView with content got from a random REST API.

Imagine now I need to send push notifications when new content is available on the API. What's the simplest way to do this ?

I'm a bit confused with the process of push notifications on Android. I took a look at Firebase, but I don't know if I mandantory need a database on Firebase that stores the result as new content is available through the API, and then triggers a notification on the database update, or if I don't need a database, etc.

As you can see it's very unclear to me so any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: if you are  using .NET for API then you should use SignalR

Comment: you do not need a database you can actually create an api in your web-api that gets triggered when something new is added and then using that api call firebase and send notifications very easily

Comment: I don't have access to the API code. I'm using a 3rd party API (i.e. a popular weather REST API). So how can I do in that case ? Do I need to add some kind of gateway, such as a Node.js API that calls the weather API and then give the results back to my app ? (so that I can trigger notifications from the Node API)

Comment: If you don't have access to the API, then _something's_ got to keep polling it to look for updates/changes, so it's either got to be your client/app or a server (e.g. in Node) that then notifies the clients/apps. You should probably also check the Ts&Cs of the 3rd-party API to make sure you're allowed to use it in this way.

Comment: You can use firebase remote config based on that show your notification

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way for achieving this is to use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases). This will help you notify users when something interesting happens, in your case, when new content is available. You can use either [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) or [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) to achieve this. I will explain to you in my answer how can be done using the new `Cloud Firestore`. For that I recommend you implement also [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). This will help you send notifications to a particular user or to a group of users when something new happens.

In order to achieve this, please consider following the steps below.

1. Implement Firebase Authentication. As soon as it is implemented, create a collection of users in which each user will be a document within users collection. Your database structure should look like this:

   ```
    Firebase-root
        |
        --- users (collection)
              |
              --- uid1 (document)
              |    |
              |    --- //user properties
              |
              --- uid2 (document)
                   |
                   --- //user properties
   ```

Besides user details, you need to add to each user a `tokenId`. You get can it very simply using the following line of code:

```
    String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

A user document should look like this:

```
    uid1
     |
     --- userName: "John"
     |
     --- userEmail: john@email.com
     |
     --- tokenId: "e_wLukMfq..." //very long token
     |
     --- //other details
```

2. Now, add a new collection to the user document named `notifications`, in which you need to add the `notification` you need to send and the `sender`, every time something new happens. It should look something like this:

   ```
    uid1
     |
     --- userName: "John"
     |
     --- userEmail: john@email.com
     |
     --- tokenId: "e_wLukMfq..." //very long token
     |
     --- notifications (collection)
     |      |
     |      --- notificationId1
     |              |
     |              --- notificationMessage: "My Notification"
     |              |
     |              --- fromUser: "My Notification"
     |
     --- //other details
   ```
3. Now you need to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to write a function in `Cloud Functions` that will listen for every new notification that appears within this reference:

   ```
    "users/{uid}/notifications/{notificationId}"
   ```

Once a new notification appears, you can use `sendToDevice` function and the `tokenId` to send the notification to a specific user. The notification will be handled by the Android system and will be displayed to the user. Note, this will work only when the app is in `background`. You can receive notifications also when the app is in the `foreground` by implementing `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: Have you achieved what you wanted? Is there everything alright?

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your time. Actually this is for personal training purpose, so it's secondary on my daily schedule. I have to work for my company before :D I'ill keep you updated

Comment: Ok, keep me posted! Cheers!

Comment: Yes thank you for your time. After getting helped by your post plus using the Firebase documentation; I finally got push notifications working :)