# Sending notification to multiple devices without using subscribeToTopic in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I know how to send notification to single user and multiple users by using subscribeToTopic ("all"), but how can I send Notification to a group of people according to my wish

Comment: firebase supports notification for a user segment but it is not customisable I believe

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, use `Cloud Functions` for sending notifications. You can send a notification to a single user or to a group of users according to your needs. I've exaplained the entire flow for doing this in my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840#48299840). So a notification can be sent, even if the user has not opened the app. He will receive the notification every time something interesting happens.