# How do you send Firebase push notifications to users subscribed to a topic from the app itself

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notifications to all the users that are subscribed to a topic after clicking a 'Send Notification' button.
So far, I've only been able to send notifications via firebase console and Postman, but never through an actual device that has the app.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Which app are you talking about?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev I've never been able to send a notification using the app itself, Ive only used the console and postman

Comment: Why not make your own app post the data to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send?

Comment: You can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840) and watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&index=16&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee).

Answer (score 0):

To send notification from an actual device that has the app to many users: You must have an Server to delivery notification.
You should try when clicking a 'Send Notification' button, do request an API server that handle push notification to all user (follow any topic all the users that are subscribed).