# Device to device push notification using firestore and node.js in android

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone please help me that how can I send notification from one device to another using Firebase Firestore and Node.js. I have already search a lot on google but found nothing. I have also seen many tutorials but most of them are outdated and are not working any more. It will be really helpful if someone share any link or some source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: Asking for a tutorials is off-topic, because there will be many competing recommendations. Everyone has their own favorite; heck, the link I just posted is to a blog post I wrote. If you're having trouble with an outdated tutorial, [create a minimal reproduction of where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a question on that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your blog it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** using Cloud Firestore and Node.js. There is also an answer of SOF regarding this tehnique which can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change)**.

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, is there everything alright?