# Data Model for Firebase/Firestore chat application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat

This is the current `Firebase`/`Firestore` data model I am using for my test chat application. However, this model is very hard to use for push notifications on Android side. I want to send push notifications to users phone when they receive messages from any of the channels they are part of. In addition file/image messages need to be added.

Any recommendations or any examples of good data models for chat applications I can use as a reference.

[image: Firestore data model]

Comment: You can refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: I was hoping to write a background service to listen to a snapshot of Channel data and then create notifications on android. Is this a wrong approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to try another approach regarding a Cloud Firestore database schema, here you can find a tutorial on how you can **[structure the database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo&list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb&t=0s&index=3)** for a Chat App.

I have also exaplained in another tutorial of mine, step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.