# How to send push notifications to all the users who have registered in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

How to send push notifications to all the users who have registered in Firebase with a button click from the app itself. For example, I want the users to know whenever someone posts.

Comment: You can use Firebase Functions for this purpose. you can study more for Firebase  Functions [Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0), [Here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/introduction-to-firebase-cloud-functions-c220613f0ef) , [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwguDeBRDCARIsAGxuU8aMeiuCZ6-Y1Ms9-WFoNurgOgpUHr454JJ2REbZI0G5_RiLZQQe5NUaAvy7EALw_wcB) and [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

Comment: If you are interested, I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Biswa during user signup you have to store the user Firebase Token , once done you will have all user's Firebase Token . On Button click call an api for sending push notification , which will trigger notofication to all user who all are registered .