# Unresolved class for firebase ".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" and ".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to import Firebase and FCM into my android app, but I'm getting

> Unresolved class for firebase ".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
>   Unresolved package for firebase ".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"

as an "error." Of course, it isn't stopping my app from running or building, but I cannot call onTokenRefresh in any class at all. So, I believe this problem is preventing me from using Firebase.

here is my app build;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            android {
                lintOptions {
                    checkReleaseBuilds false
                    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
                    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
                    abortOnError false
                }
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPdhN.png)

Comment: The `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` and `MyFirebaseMessagingService` don't automatically come from importing Firebase. They are classes that you need to create yourself. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That was what i was following. I have that exact page opened right now. But when I was walking through it, I couldn't add those services in the app gradle

Comment: Please add the content of your build.gradle file and please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I did add the screenshot of my app build.gradle. You dont see it?

Comment: That's the Android Manifest file and I have asked you for the build.gradle file.

Comment: @AlexMamo my bad, i get them confused often. I added the app build in the question now

Comment: Looks fine to me. So have you created those 2 classes?

Comment: @AlexMamo Classes? No, I just added those chunks of code into my gradle and manifest like Google told me to

Comment: As Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment, in order to use those classes in your Manifest file you first need to create them.

Comment: The Java and Kotlin code for `MyFirebaseMessagingService` is right under where it tells you to add the dependencies to your `build.gradle` file. Implementing that class will get rid of one error. I actually didn't see the code for `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` in there, but assume it's equally findable with a search.

Comment: @AlexMamo Google didn't tell me I had to make the class. I thought i was just adding firebase like a plugin/dependency. So how do i even make this class? i thought i was just adding in Firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What? Im sorry im very new and youre confusing

Comment: Your manifest declares that your app contains `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` and a `MyFirebaseMessagingService` classes, which it doesn't. That's what the error message means. You don't need either class to work with basic Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications (docs: "A service that extends FirebaseMessagingService. This is required **if you want to do any message handling beyond receiving notifications on apps in the background**."). But if you declare them, you must implement them. And if you don't want to use them (yet), you should not include their declaration from your app's manifest file

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh, so im trying to reference a class that doesnt exist in my xml? ok, so I can just get rid of it? Why is it called a service then? What happens when I don't have it? Do I even need it to be able to send a notif to everyone that logs into my app?

Comment: If you don't have `MyFirebaseMessagingService`, you will just see the default notifications when your app is not active, and no notifications when your app **is** active and foregrounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you two classes should look like:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        sendNotification(notification, data);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
        //Send notification
    }
}
```

Comment: As I see those classes are already added. If you'll add both classes, your errors will disappear. Can  you confrim this?

Comment: Everything works, but OnTokenRefresh is deprecated along with FirebaseInstanceIDService

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! It is an example. And yes, you should use the latest version. Cheers!

Comment: I have another question if you wanna hear it. It should be fairly easy to solve. I dont want to make it another whole question on this site because itll probably be taken down for being a bad question

Comment: No, we should stick to one question at a time. If you have another problem after this one is solved, post a new question for that problem with its own MCVE.

Comment: MCVE? whats that?

Comment: Oh no, it isnt a scripting problem. Its just a question on what i should follow if i want to make an app that sends a notif to every phone logged into the app. Do i use Group Messaging? Topic messaging? Device Groups? Upstream messages?

Comment: You should use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: Thats what i am using, but underneath FCM, there is multiple ways to handle messaging, and group messaging. And i dont know which one i should use

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.

Comment: Thats a bit too confusing for a beginner like me. Ill just make it a group message