# Firebase database Notifications sent to one device Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some questions concerning android firebase database in order for me to go in the right direction. What I am trying to do: 
I have one client side that sends notification to one of the Two server sides I have. However I can not manage to send the notification to only one of the two server sides, when I send a notification it sends it directly to both Server sides, and this is what I am trying to figure out.

I am using an authentification for users in both client and servers sides, however is it essential to have two server sides? Or can I just filter my notifications with the users?

I am just asking this in order to go in the right direction.
Thank you.

Comment: What are these 2 server sides?

Comment: I tried with a second server to see if when I sent a notification from the client side if it would receive, or not, the notification. And it did.

Comment: So basically, I have 1 client side that send notification to both server sides (or we can call them (Restaurant side)), while I am trying to send the notification to only one of the "restaurant side" (server side)

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't mix the client and server side terms?

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send [notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17) to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840).