# Send a push notification from one device to another

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have 2 users, is it possible for user1 to send user2 a push notification if user2's app is in the background?

The scenario is: user1 updates a field in a Firestore document. At this point, I want user1 to send a push notification to user2 notifying them of the change.

At the moment, user2 can successfully detect document changes when the app is in the foreground via `document.addSnapshotListener()`.

However when user2 leaves the app their `snapshotListener` is removed.

Is there a way I can send a push notification from user1 to user2 while only using Firestore and built-in Android APIs or Firebase Cloud Messaging? Or do I *have* to use something like Google Cloud Functions for this to work?

Comment: Use xmpp for that

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.