# How to send push notification to specific devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I got two mobile apps for service provider and customer, i need to send push notifications for service provider user once the customer requests a specific service type. So it needs to be filtered and send only for those who can provide such a service. Therefore web api needs to send the notification only for specific users, how can i do that with `firebase` should i use, `device mac` or `registration id` generated by `firebase`.

Any help

Comment: there are some thing called topics https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging, or save the device token in server when user subscribes to a service and send notification to only those tokens

Comment: I don't recommend Topics because Topics are supposed to be "public" and readable by anyone who wants to subscribe to it. It's not meant to send private messages.

Comment: Check also **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)** out.

Answer (score 3):

1. register a new project in FCM console.
2. Make android/ios and web(for configuration) application.
3. The first-time app will be loaded it gives device token and store to the database.
4. by using device token you can send a notification to a particular device.

Reference link:- https://www.djamware.com/post/5c6ccd1f80aca754f7a9d1ec/push-notification-using-ionic-4-and-firebase-cloud-messaging

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to get the fire base token from android app.
2. Register your mobile app in Firebase console.
3. If you have any user login api and database, send the fire base token while user 
   login your app and save the token against the user.
4. Whenever the user request for service you can get the token of the particular user 
   and send a message to fire base api with that token from server side.
5. It will automatically send the message to that particular device whoever login your 
   app.
6. Make sure you update the token while if other user login your app in same device.