# I want to make a notifications with dates saved in Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I am making an app on Android Studio with Java. I have a realtime database with some pieces of information and specially dates. I want my app to display a notitification when those dates are near. I've been searching for information, making an notificacion is easy but I don't know how to invoke the notification.

[image: This is my database]

Comment: Have you tried to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)?

Comment: No I haven't, how could it be?

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840) that can help you achieve that. Works also in case of Firebase Realtime Database.