# Firebase Notifications in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase notifications on my app.
I was wandering if it's possible to send a notification every time I add a new child to a certain table.
For example, I create a new event (like a concert or something) and add it to my Firebase Database trought my phone. Is it possible that firebase send to every user some field on that event as a notification (like title and description)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use topics.
We usually define a topic (e.g `allUsers`) and subscribe all users to that ropic
And then send the notification to that topic. It has a delivery rate under 2minutes of 88% (some users might turned their net off, some may receiving after 2 minutes, or not at all)

Take a look at this  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: It is possible to add a image to the message recived?