# How to send notification to a specific user when the data present in firestore changes even if the app is not working in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have read many different answers on this topic but I couldn't understand any of them. I have saved my data in firestore hence the data is in the form of collections and documents. Please send the solution for android studio.

Comment: I have explained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.

Comment: Before I implement it can you please tell me if this method works when the application is closed or not

Comment: Yes, it works in both situations.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented this feature in my chatting app in which user will get notify if someone request to chat with them.

Refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkA53Ga6R1k&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcRHjHyZAxm_Mq4qvtnundo0) push notification tutorial.