# Sending push notification to stored Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send notifications to another device number after completion of certain process by current device. e.g. If A user completes the operation then B will get notification.

I am maintaing Realtime database by having all mobile numbers with unique ids.like below:

```
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("Logins");
        String id = reference.push().getKey();
        reference.child(id).setValue(mobile);
```

and data is:

```
cofy-ac782-default-rtdb
    ->Logins
      -> -M_1PKZ6x-mLQQ22zoFM: "888886666699"
      -> -M_1PeRIIsM3QGuwmelW: "888886666790"
```

Above two are two users having these mobiles. So, I would like to send notifiction from first user to second.

I am bit confused, if i would be able to use this data for notification using Cloud messaging.
Is it possible that i refer this database and send generate push notifications?

Help is appreciated.

Regards,
PD

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I have explained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using Node.js. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.

Answer (score 1):

You must refer to firebase functions that will help you to send notification to specific person when `UserA` complete some task and your realtime database gets update at that moment firebase functions will do the rest.

For Firebase functions you must have little knowledge of `Node.Js`.

Refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) link.