# Receive an order after subscription. Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, subscription, in-app-subscription

I'm new to app development and I'm stuck at one point.

I have an application with a subscription and when done I would like to receive a kind of report by email, SMS or whatever is possible. Just username and email are enough.
I have a Firebase Realtime Database configured with this data.

Is it possible to get this data and send it when the subscription is complete?

Thanks all!!

Comment: A notification maybe?

Comment: Yes, I just need to know which user did a subscription.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find an answer on [how to send notification using Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840).

Comment: This recommendation is amazing I am planning to add this in the future. I saved it here, thanks. But at this time I don't need to send notifications to the user.

Explaining better:
* I have an app with 100 users
*One of them buy a subscription.

Is there a way to know which user bought a subscription?

Comment: You should authenticate the users and once a subscription is bought, send a notification.

Comment: I have the users authenticated and their data saved on Firebase Realtime Database (I can change to Cloud Firestore if it fits better) but for now, I don't want to send a notification to the user. I need to see if was Mary, Jhon, Chris or any one of the 100 users who bought a subscription.